# change size of devtmpfs /dev/

Tags: kernel, udev, tmpfs

My new kernel has `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS` enabled, and thus my `/dev` is mounted as `devtmpfs`. My old kernel was not using `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS`, and /dev used to be mounted as plain `tmpfs`.

Now I have noticed, the size of `/dev/` is ridiculously large: 8GB, which is half of my RAM:

```
df | grep devtmpfs
devtmpfs         devtmpfs  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
```

In the past, when my `/dev` was mounted as `tmpfs`, the size used to be 10MB

```
df | grep tmpfs
tmpfs                 tmpfs        10M     0   10M   0% /dev
```

Seems to me, 10MB is more than enough for `/dev`. Why does `/dev/` allocate 50% of my RAM by default? Where can I change this ?

Comment: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2b2af54a5bb6f7e80ccf78f20084b93c398c3a8b - its just tmpfs. `mount -o remount,size=5% none /dev` probably. anyway, it's not used - it's at 0%! 50% is just the tmpfs mount default.

Answer (score 6):

No, the size of `/dev` is not 8GB. That's the *maximum* size. The size that it actually uses in memory is proportional to the *used* size; memory is allocated as needed.

Linux doesn't have man pages for all filesystems, in which case you should look in the `mount` man page. But `tmpfs` does have a man page and it does mention this.

Comment: yes I know, but it could "potentially" grow to up to 8GB. Using  50% of RAM as default size for '/dev'  makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. I see no legitimate reason to allow `/dev/` bigger than 10MB. So why should I use default value of 8GB ?

Comment: @MartinVegter Well it will only use as much as it needs... That default is there because there needs to be one.